# Map Multiple network drives windows 2012 domain controller

Tags: networking, windows-server-2012, vbscript, windows-domain, mapped-drive

I have found this script to map single drive and Relabel the Drive:

```
' 
Option Explicit
Dim objNetwork, strDrive, objShell, objUNC
Dim strRemotePath, strDriveLetter, strNewName 
' 
strDriveLetter = "H:" 
strRemotePath = "\\FileServer\sharedfolder" 
strNewName = "Save Your Files Here"

' Section which actually (re)names the Mapped Drive
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
objShell.NameSpace(strDriveLetter).Self.Name = strNewName

WScript.Quit

' End of Example VBScript.
```

I have multiple shared folder to be shared with some specific users groups.
How to modify this script to map multiple drives when user logs onto the domain

other shares

```
\\FileServer\Share1
\\FileServer\Share2
\\FileServer\Share3
\\FileServer\ShareXX
```

I know this can be done using net use. but this does not allow Relabeling of shares.

```
net use x: \\FileServer\Share1
net use y: \\FileServer\Share2
net use z: \\FileServer\Share3
net use J: \\FileServer\Sharexx
```

Comment: This would be a lot easier with Group Policy Preferences than a script.

Comment: @Twisty , I tried with group policy but for some reason i could not make it work. that why i posted this script